# Aggregate Query returning multiple records

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregation

I have the following table (*simplified*):

```
RecordID       bigint         IDENTITY
ItemID         bigint
ConfigID       varchar
Status         varchar
StatusDate     date
```

**Sample Data**:

```
001  04  1E  10    2007-08-14 13:57:54
002  04  1E  12    2007-08-21 16:10:21
003  04  1D  10    2007-09-27 17:14:13
004  04  1D  43    2011-01-10 13:44:50
005  04  1B  50    2008-06-20 09:09:51
006  05  1A  17    2007-12-18 14:04:56
007  05  1A  11    2007-10-17 08:23:52
008  05  1A  12    2007-10-19 12:54:18
009  05  1B  12    2007-11-02 09:23:54
010  05  1B  40    2010-06-17 09:34:33
011  07  1A  12    2007-11-19 14:48:06
012  07  1A  12    2007-11-19 15:02:48
013  07  1B  40    2011-01-10 14:36:16
014  08  1B  10    2009-05-22 11:14:42
015  08  1B  12    2007-11-20 17:02:44
016  08  1A  12    2007-12-12 16:11:57
017  08  1A  10    2009-11-12 11:12:45
018  08  1C  35    2011-01-10 18:30:10
019  08  1D  12    2009-10-14 14:34:47
020  08  1D  10    2009-10-14 14:35:09
```

Herein lies my problem:

I need to be able to have end-users query this data to return records that will display the latest status and statusdate for each unique combination of itemid and config.  So, using the above sample I want to return a record set matching the following:

```
002  04  1E  12    2007-08-21 16:10:21
004  04  1D  43    2011-01-10 13:44:50
005  04  1B  50    2008-06-20 09:09:51
006  05  1A  17    2007-12-18 14:04:56
010  05  1B  40    2010-06-17 09:34:33
012  07  1A  12    2007-11-19 15:02:48
013  07  1B  40    2011-01-10 14:36:16
017  08  1A  10    2009-11-12 11:12:45
018  08  1C  35    2011-01-10 18:30:10
020  08  1D  10    2009-10-14 14:35:09
```

In plain english:  I need to be able to return the latest status and status date for each item's configuration(s).

Any help in this regard would be extremely appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in SQL server 2005+, you can use CTE for this:

```
;with cte as
(
  select recordid,
    itemid,
    configid,
    status,
    statusdate,
    row_number() over(partition by itemid, configid
                        order by statusdate desc) rn
  from yourtable
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
order by recordid
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f210a/1)

Comment: This works a treat!  I get some _minor_ flaky inclusions but it is not based solely on this query, it is from other incoming parameters not listed here.  I **accept** this one wholeheartedly!

Comment: Bluefeet,  I had to come back and  again give you much thanks for this snippet!  If you are ever in the Northern Virginia area let me know, lunch is on me.

Comment: @Bear if the any of the answers work, be sure to accept it so future visitors know the answer.  No lunch needed, I am happy to help out. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do the `GROUP BY` clause in a subquery. Try,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    yourtable a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT      ItemID, ConfigID, MAX([StatusDate]) maxStat
            FROM        yourtable
            GROUP BY    ItemID,ConfigID
        ) b on a.configID = b.configID AND
                a.[statusDate] = b.MaxStat AND
                a.ItemID = b.ItemID
Order by RecordID
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f210a/10)

Comment: I think it has two problem, he needs itemID + configID as groupBy condition. And what if you have the status twice for the same? Then he will get that row twice instead of one. Example two: 04  1B  50, 04  1B  50 with different dates.

Comment: the status columns should be changed to StatusDate to get the most recent, rather than the max "Status"

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I need to return the record (row) of each item's configuration by examining each item's configurations's max statusdate.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: @Bear why is `014  08  1B  10    2009-05-22 11:14:42` not included in your desired result? is it typo error?

Comment: Yeah, it is... or a test to see if you were paying attention, yeah let's go with that.  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    RecordID,
    ItemID,
    ConfigID,
    Status,
    StatusDate
FROM
    (SELECT
        RecordID,
        ItemID,
        ConfigID,
        Status,
        StatusDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemId,ConfigID ORDER BY StatusDate DESC) As StatusOrder
    FROM
        MyTable) Statuses
WHERE
    StatusOrder= 1
```